# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant

Tags: java, enums

I have problems with my enum.

Here it is :

```
public enum DataEnum {
    NAME_PEOPLE("NAME_PEOPLE"),
    FIRSTNAME_PEOPLE("FIRSTNAME_PEOPLE"),
    ID("ID"),
    PASS("PASS"),
    NEW_MAIL("NEW_MAIL");

    private  String name;
    private DataEnum(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setValue(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }
}
```

I'm using it there :

```
public String transform(String textToTransform, People people){
        Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("#(.+?)#");
        Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(textToTransform);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String s = matcher.group(1);
            switch (s) {
                case "FIRSTNAME_PEOPLE":
                    DataEnum.valueOf(s).setValue(people.getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "NAME_PEOPLE":
                    DataEnum.valueOf(s).setValue(people.getName());
                    break;
                case "ID":
                    DataEnum.valueOf(s).setValue(people.getEmail());
                    break;
                case "PASS":
                    DataEnum.valueOf(s).setValue(people.getPassword());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            textToTransform = textToTransform.replace("#" + DataEnum.valueOf(s) + "#", DataEnum.valueOf(s).getValue());
        }
        return textToTransform;
    }
```

And I get the following error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
>   fr.pdf.utils.DataEnum.FIRSTNAME_PEOPLE

EDIT :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
>   fr.pdf.utils.DataEnum.FIRSTNAME_PEOPLE    at
>   java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)     at
>   fr.pdf.utils.DataEnum.valueOf(DataEnum.java:3)
>     at
>   fr.pdf.services.impl.MailServiceImpl.transform(MailServiceImpl.java:160)
>     at
>   fr.pdf.services.impl.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:84)
>     at
>   fr.pdf.dao.impl.People.update(People.java:372)

Line 160 correspond to :

```
textToTransform = textToTransform.replace("#" + DataEnum.valueOf(s) + "#", DataEnum.valueOf(s).getValue());
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktarce

Comment: Aside from the actual problem, modifying an enum value seems like a *really* bad idea to me. That's global state, basically.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Why would you want to modify an existing enum anyway?

Comment: I think op has not understand what an enum is for

Comment: Yes I agree with you but I didn't find a better solution. 
If you have, i'm listening carefully.
To explain quickly what I need : I have a text containing variables between hashtags, like #NAME_PEOPLE#. These variables have to be filled by my current user values. 
The name of these variables must be available on the front side for the admin of the app.

Comment: What about a HashMap? key is the tag name and value the current value from the people object. This will work with concurrent threads, too. Your Enum solution will not ...

Comment: What exactly does your `String textToTransform` contain? Is it possible that text matched by group 1 from `#(.*?)#` (here `FIRSTNAME_PEOPLE`) contains some extra (invisible) characters? Could you print its codepoints (result of `Arrays.toString(s.codePoints().toArray())`).

Comment: A hashmap in an abstract class for example ? 

Yes you are right, there was a space in the text, like #NAME_PEOPLE # 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Drop the enum and do this :)

```
public String transform(String textToTransform, People people){
    Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("#(.+?)#");
    Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(textToTransform);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group(1);
        String replaceWith = null;
        switch (s) {
            case "FIRSTNAME_PEOPLE":
                replaceWith = people.getFirstName();
                break;
            case "NAME_PEOPLE":
                replaceWith = people.getName();
                break;
            case "ID":
                replaceWith = people.getEmail();
                break;
            case "PASS":
                replaceWith = people.getPassword();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        textToTransform = textToTransform.replace("#" + s + "#", replaceWith);
    }
    return textToTransform;
}
```

Comment: Not possible for me, I need to keep the "hashtag" name somewhere because i need to give the list of them front side.

Comment: The other solution for me is to stored the hashtag names in the db and get them front side. But I would like to avoid db call.

Comment: Then save the tags in a ArrayList and you may add an additional contains check before the switch statement. But convert a String into an Enum to convert it back to a String makes somehow no sense to me.

Comment: Ok i'll change to this. Thank you for your advices.